# Formatting for thousands separator interferes with '0.00' formatting

Tags: android

I have to display amount in decimal format, 
e.g. `123459.23` shown as `123,459.23` and `0.00` shown as `0.00`

I'm using below format but '0.00' shows as '0.0000.00' with below formatting.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simplified description, corrected spelling. Focused the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this:

```
System.out.printf( "%,d\n", 58625 );
System.out.printf( "%,.2f\n", 58625.21 );
System.out.printf( "%,.2f", 12345678.9 );
```

Output:

```
58,625
58,625.21
12,345,678.90
```

Comment: if i have amount as 0.00 will it work  if i choose      System.out.printf( "%,.2f\n", 58625.21 );

Comment: System.out.printf( "%,.2f\n", 0.00 ); yes it will work for 0.00

Comment: 58625.21  is in string and it gives  java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Comment: System.out.printf( "%,.2f\n", 58625.21 ); using this for 0.00 i m gettibg 0.,000.00

Comment: can any one help?